# Why are two dialogs using 700 weight font after a system switch to UTF-8?

Tags: c++, utf-8, mfc, windows-10

On multiple computers with Windows 10, where we just change the Operating System to use UTF-8 (beta) codepage, two dialogs (out of hundreds in our app) went haywire.  The following code was added to fix them.

The question is, why is this suddenly necessary?  Why only two dialogs? I cannot find anything font-related in the .rc files nor the .cpp/.h files.

```
static CFont newFont;
void SetDialogFontToNormal(CDialog* c)
{
  c->ModifyStyleEx(0, WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME);
  CFont *main = c->GetFont();
  LOGFONT lf;
  main->GetLogFont(&lf);

  lf.lfWeight = 100; // WAS 700.  WHY?

  newFont.CreateFontIndirectW(&lf);
  c->SetFont(&newFont, true);
  for (CWnd* pControl = c->GetWindow(GW_CHILD); pControl; pControl = pControl->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
  {
    pControl->SetFont(&newFont, true);
  }
}

BOOL DwgEdit::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    SetDialogFontToNormal(this);
```

Dialog resource definition:

```
IDD_DRAWINGEDITOR DIALOGEX 0, 0, 305, 229
STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
CAPTION "Drawing Editor"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
LISTBOX         IDC_DWGLIST,7,5,104,177,LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | 
   LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
PUSHBUTTON      "&Add",IDC_ADDBUTTON,7,186,49,14
.... more controls
END
```

**Preliminary answer, based on comments below.
Replacing the FONT line as follows seems to work.
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1**

On request, and for comparison, this other dialog works:

```
IDD_ACTDRAWING DIALOG 0, 0, 135, 214
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Active Drawing"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    LISTBOX         IDC_DWGLIST,0,0,134,176,LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,13,195,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,71,195,50,14
...
END
```

Comment: I mean.. how would we know?

Comment: Could you please show the resource of those two dialogs? Do they specify the font? Different from other dialogs? BTW, "normal" is 400; 100 is for "thin".

Comment: @blindy very good question.  at vlad: done.

Comment: Are there, by chance, invisible characters in those dialog resources (e.g. ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER)?

Comment: Maybe.  How can i find invisible characters?

Comment: Do your other dialogs use `"MS Sans Serif"` or do they use something else?  As I recall some frameworks perform font substitutions.

Comment: I think you got it!  Many use MS Sans but most use MS Shell Dlg.  And replacing in one dialog fixes it.  And yet... some MS Sand Serif dialogs work just fine still.

Comment: Could you please check if (after the OS change) you have that `MS Sand Serif` installed? If not - Windows would substitute it to something "similar", possibly based on what fonts are already in use by your app.

Comment: Could you also post one of the dialog that works?

Comment: @VladFeinstein "Microsoft Sans Serif" is in the system's font collection.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jabberwocky most of the dialogs worked, and they are all different one from another.  I don't know what can be gleaned.